# Doxygen not recognizing remarks xml tag in comments

Tags: doxygen

For the following comment block, doxygen is not adding a remarks tag to the outputted xml. Is this the correct use of the xml remarks tag in the comments block? It appears to be supported in doxygen : http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html

Comment Block:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an AchievementsResult object containing the first page of achievements
/// for a player of the specified title.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="titleId">The title ID.</param>
/// <param name="type">The achievement type to retrieve.</param>
/// <param name="orderby">Controls how the list of achievements is ordered.</param>
/// <param name="skipItems">The number of achievements to skip.</param>
/// <param name="maxItems">The maximum number of achievements the result can contain.  Pass 0 to attempt
/// to retrieve all items.</param>
/// <returns>An AchievementsResult object that contains a list of Achievement objects.</returns>
/// <remarks>
/// Returns an IAsyncOperation<TResult> object that represents the state of the asynchronous operation.
/// Completion of the asynchronous operation is signaled by using a handler that is passed to the
/// IAsyncOperation<TResult>.Completed property. When the asynchronous operation is complete, the result of the
/// operation can be retrieved by using the IAsyncOperation<TResult>.GetResults method.
///
/// See AchievementsResult::GetNextAsync to page in the next set of results.
///
/// This method calls V2 GET /users/xuid({xuid})/achievements.
/// </remarks>
```

Doxygen XML :

```
...
</simplesect>
</para>
<para>Returns an IAsyncOperation&lt;TResult&gt; object that represents the state of the asynchronous operation. Completion of the asynchronous operation is signaled by using a handler that is passed to the IAsyncOperation&lt;TResult&gt;.Completed property. When the asynchronous operation is complete, the result of the operation can be retrieved by using the IAsyncOperation&lt;TResult&gt;.GetResults method.</para>
<para>See <ref refid="class_d3337fa7a" kindref="member">AchievementsResult::GetNextAsync</ref> to page in the next set of results.</para>
<para>This method calls V2 GET /users/xuid({xuid})/achievements.</para>
</detaileddescription>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen's XML output follows a different schema than the C# XML input (which doesn't even have a proper schema defined). So `<remarks>`...`</remarks>` in the input ends up as a set of paragraphs within the `<detaileddescription>`...`</detaileddescription>` container in the output.

Comment: Would you need more information on the schema than what's provided here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx

Is there a way to log a feature request?